# Build STASM with OpenCV for iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, cmake, makefile, stasm

I'm trying to build stasm for iOS for facial recognition, using OpenCV.

The steps I'm doing are:

- Build OpenCV for iOS (python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios)
- Download the build script from here: https://github.com/juan-cardelino/stasm, and edit the CMakeCache.txt to: OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/Users/xxx/opencv-2.4.9/ios/build/iPhoneOS-armv7s
- Open the Xcode project generated and compile.
- Use cmake, everything works fine.
- Use make, get this error:

> ```
> [ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/apps/minimal.cpp.o
> Linking CXX executable minimal
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Release'
> ld: framework not found CoreImage
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make[2]: *** [minimal] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/minimal.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

What am I doing wrong? And, is this the way to build it for iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will find `CoreImage.framework` within `QuartzCore.framework`, just import it

```
Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework
```

Comment: How do I import it in the make file?